# How to treat each coefficients of GF(2^n) as variable in sage?

Tags: sage

I know how to calculate over a GF(2^n) as below.

```
sage: F.<X> = GF(2^256)
sage: X^256 * X
X^11 + X^6 + X^3 + X
```

But I don't know how to treat each coefficients as variable.

For example, let `a, b, c` are `GF(2)` elements.

Then what I want to do is likely below.

```
# This is not a valid code
sage: (aX^10 + b) * (aX^5)
aX^15 + abX^5
```

I don't know how to define GF(2) variables `a, b, c`. I tried to use `var` function in sage but it seems not fit. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just work over the polynomial ring R = F[a, b], or F[a, b, c] if c is also really needed, where F is the given field.

(Or, when also fractions are involved, over the associated fractional field of R.) For instance:

```
F.<X> = GF(2^256)
R.<a,b> = PolynomialRing(F)

expression = (a*X^10 + b) * (a*X^5 + 1)^2
print(expression)
```

And the print works:

```
(X^20)*a^3 + (X^10)*a^2*b + (X^10)*a + b
```

---

*Later EDIT:*

From the comment it seems that we should also implement further relations that better match the fact that a, b, ... are elements in the field GF(2). In this case, we may work in the quotient ring modulo the ideal J generated by the relations a = a², b = b², and so on.

I will use A, B, ... for a, b, ... modulo these relations:

```
F.<X> = GF(2^256)
R.<a,b> = PolynomialRing(F)
J = [ g - g^2 for g in R.gens() ]
Q.<A, B> = R.quotient(J)

expression = (a*X^10 + b) * (a*X^5 + 1)^2
print(f'The given expression is:\n{expression}\n')

expression_simplified = Q(expression).lift()
print(f'The given expression is simplified:\n{expression_simplified}')
```

Results:

```
The given expression is:
(X^20)*a^3 + (X^10)*a^2*b + (X^10)*a + b

The given expression is simplified:
(X^10)*a*b + (X^20 + X^10)*a + b
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice answer. However, I think a and b is GF(2^256) instead of GF(2) in your code

Comment: The question wants in the last part that  $a,b,c,\dots$ are variables, and my understanding was that some expressions in $a,b,c,\dots$ should be computed. Then the way to work with "variables" is as above. Of course, if $a,b$ are in `GF(2)` we may further simplify a lot expressions, using relations like a = a². Is this the wanted behaviour? If yes, we may also introduce an ideal and make computation modulo this ideal.